# Low-Level API Multipart File Upload Process is not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are trying to upload file through Multipart File Upload Process. By using this given below code:

```
while (!feof($file)) {

$result = $s3->uploadPart(array(
    'Bucket'     => $bucket,
    'Key'        => $key,
    'UploadId'   => $uploadId,
    'PartNumber' => $partNumber,
    'Body'       => fread($file, filesize($filename))
));
$parts[] = array(
    'PartNumber' => $partNumber++,
    'ETag'       => $result['ETag'],
);
}
```

// 4. Complete multipart upload.

```
$result = $s3->completeMultipartUpload(array(

    'Bucket'   => $bucket,
    'Key'      => $key,
    'UploadId' => $uploadId,
    'Parts'    => $parts,
));
$url = $result['Location'];

fclose($file);
```

By using this code, file is converted into Multipart but unavailable to upload the file. It's showing this type of error through print_r:

```
Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model Object
(

[structure:protected] => 
[data:protected] => Array
    (
        [ServerSideEncryption] => 
        [ETag] => "fcfc6838dfrtefr87b27b642e7d63021"
        [SSECustomerAlgorithm] => 
        [SSECustomerKeyMD5] => 
        [RequestId] => 4RTYPEFE054567369BD46D
    )

)
```

Uploading part 2 of /tmp/phplA534j.

```
Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model Object
(

[structure:protected] => 
[data:protected] => Array
    (
        [ServerSideEncryption] => 
        [ETag] => "d41d8uytrf67fdfrf00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
        [SSECustomerAlgorithm] => 
        [SSECustomerKeyMD5] => 
        [RequestId] => YTYPO67167874586EF802536C
    )

)
```

Uploading part 3 of /tmp/phplA534j.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Two things. First, you can use `SourceFile` instead of `Body`:

```
$result = $s3->uploadPart(array(
    'Bucket'     => $bucket,
    'Key'        => $key,
    'UploadId'   => $uploadId,
    'PartNumber' => $partNumber,
    'SourceFile'       => 'Path/To/Your/File.ext')
));
```

Second, That is not the correct way for completing your upload:

```
$result = $s3->completeMultipartUpload(array(

    'Bucket'   => $bucket,
    'Key'      => $key,
    'UploadId' => $uploadId,
    'MultipartUpload'    =>array('Parts'=>  $parts),
));
```